# Receivers Email (to) should change based on drop-down selection in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying to solve a problem where there are 5 towers and each has respective recipients' list.
When a particular tower is selected the form should auto-populate the respective email ids in the to textbox for user.

**SOLUTION I TRIED:**

1. I tried to add a new method 'Selection_Change' to dropdown for tower which contains the email ids for each tower respectively.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="txtTowerValue" runat="server" SkinID="EmailTextbox" Font-Size="14px" Width="580px" Height="30px" BorderStyle="None">onselectedIndexchanged="Selection_Change"> 

 <asp:ListItem Value="--Please Select--">--Please Select--</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="AO">AO</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="MOD">MOD</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="IO">IO</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="SD">SD</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="Security">Security</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList></td>
```

**Selection_Change method code:**

```
protected void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtTowerValue.SelectedItem.Text == "AO")
    {
        txtNotifTo.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToAO"].ToString();
    }
    if (txtTowerValue.SelectedItem.Text == "IO")
    {
        txtNotifTo.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToIO"].ToString();
    }
    if (txtTowerValue.SelectedItem.Text == "MOD")
    {
        txtNotifTo.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToMOD"].ToString();
    }
    if (txtTowerValue.SelectedItem.Text == "SD")
    {
        txtNotifTo.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToSD"].ToString();
    }
    if (txtTowerValue.SelectedItem.Text == "Security")
    {
        txtNotifTo.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToSecurity"].ToString();
    }
}
```

*I also went through few suggestions which mentioned adding Autopostback=true for the drop-down but in that case the page reloads and the pop-up form closes down which is not helpful for my problem. I was hoping if anyone has any suggestions to tackle this problem using jQuery/Javascript or can give input on the code that I have put out here.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"tackle this problem using jQuery/Javascript"* - If you don't want to reload the page then that's exactly what you would use.  jQuery isn't strictly necessary, but to perform logic client-side in the browser you would certainly use JavaScript.  You are very much encouraged to try that.

Comment: I am new to Javascript @David , could you help me out on how to approach the problem using Javascript.

Comment: In JavaScript you would attach an event handler to the form element in question (likely a `change` handler on a `<select>` element) and in that handler function you would perform whatever logic you want to perform.